# Bug report/rule breakage; proper course of action after a flag is marked as helpful, but nothing is done?

Tags: support, flags, helpful-flags, avatar

A while ago (June 16th, 2020), I happened upon an animated GIF as a user's profile avatar.  After researching and finding that avatar GIFs were not allowed/prevented, etc.  I flagged a post by the user explaining this.  Eventually, that flag was marked helpful.  However, as it stands today, the user in question still has the animated avatar(even across all sites I've checked).  I'm not going to be linking the profile of the user in question to avoid shaming; moderators can easily find the flag as it is the second most recent one(on meta).

While I am aware there are worse things out there to flag (and I do do so when I run into them), the way the flag was handled makes me wonder if there's been a change in policy to allow higher-rep users to use animated avatars.

Of course, it could have been a misclick, but I don't want to cross a line; if I re-flag, it could potentially be seen as being a nuisance on purpose, which I of course wish to avoid.

What is the proper course of action if a flag is marked helpful in this regard, but nothing is apparently done?

Comment: A flag is easier to deal with than a public meta post, I'd have just flagged again "Avatar is still there, it should be removed, right?" Even if you were wrong (which you aren't), worst-case, it gets declined and you could start a meta discussion on it to try to get everyone onto the same page

Comment: Could it be that the mod did reset the profile but that the user re-uploaded their avatar again?

Comment: Users with high reputation don't receive special treatment, other than the [privileges outlined](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: I’ve found your flag and reset the avatar properly. The animation was only visible on the profile page and nowhere else so the mod that handled your flag originally probably thought the animation issue had resolved itself before we got to your flag.

Comment: I’ve found your flag and reset the avatar properly. The animation was only visible on the profile page and nowhere else so the mod that handled your flag originally probably thought the animation issue had resolved itself before we got to your flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For flags on user accounts you generally should not expect any *obvious instant* outcome for flags marked "helpful" - unless there is something outrageous moderators would try to contact user first to sort out the issue/behavior on the site.

In this case 2+ month is long enough time for the user to update their profile back (if a moderator originally changed the avatar image) or never act on the moderator's message (if one was sent instead). Note that there could be ways (just guess) when avatar get updated without user's direct action as changes on account may pull in updated image - so blaming the user for doing it on-purpose best left to moderators/CM who should be able to know the exact reason.

Flagging it again should be perfectly fine. Consider adding an explanation like "it was possibly dealt with in response to my flag June 16th, 2020 but the problematic image is there again".